# Any Bluetooth library out there to with PythonCE?

Tags: python, windows-mobile, bluetooth, pythonce

[PythonCE](http://www.pythonce.org) is a Python port for Windows CE and Windows Mobile. I'm currently working on a project that uses Bluetooth (actually PyBluez) to communicate with a remote device. My project works on Windows, Linux and Mac. The only problem I have porting it to Windows CE or Windows Mobile devices is that I don't know of any Bluetooth library that works with PythonCE.

My question is: Is there any Bluetooth library out there for PythonCE?